# 3D Cooley-Tukey FFT

Tags: fourier-transform

To compute the $N$-point DFT
$$ X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] W_N^{kn} $$
where $N = N_1 N_2$, we can write the indices as $n = N_2 n_1 + n_2$ and $k = k_1 + N_1 k_2$, (effectively packing the data into a 2D array) and then

$$
X[k_1 + N_1 k_2] = \sum_{n_1=0}^{N_1 - 1} \sum_{n_2 = 0}^{N_2 - 1} x[N_2 n_1 + n_2] W_N^{kn}
$$
and
$$
W_N^{kn} = W_N^{(N_2 n_1 + n_2)(k_1 + N_1 k_2)} = W_N^{N_2 n_1 k_1} W_N^{N_1N_2n_1k_2}W_N^{n_2 k_1} W_N^{N_1 n_2 k_2} = W_{N_1}^{n_1 k_1} W_N^{n_2 k_1} W_{N_2}^{n_2 k_2}
$$

so
$$
X[k_1 + N_1 k_2] = \sum_{n_1=0}^{N_1 - 1} \left( \sum_{n_2 = 0}^{N_2 - 1} x[N_2 n_1 + n_2] W_{N_1}^{k_1 n_1} W_N^{n_2 k_1} \right) W_{N_2}^{k_2 n_2} 
$$

This means we can compute the DFT of the columns of the 2D matrix, then multiply by twiddle factors $W_N^{n_2 k_1}$, then compute the DFT of the rows.

Does this extend to 3 dimensions? i.e. if $N =N_1 N_2 N_3$ can we pack the data into a 3D array, compute the DFT across each axis and multiply by twiddle factors? If so how would the indexing work and what would the twiddle factors look like.

Thanks for any help